# d.out.file is not working

Tags: grass-gis, png

I'm trying to use 'd.out.file' to save the displayed map to a PNG file. It failed and produced this message: "Command 'd.out.file' not yet implemented in the GUI. Try adding it as a command layer instead."

How can I resolve this? It also seems that I cannot run other d.* commands

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to run it using the terminal (in command line)

Comment: I used the GRASS 6.4.0 with MSYS in order to type in the command-line window, but there was still an error because I cannot create a monitor

Comment: d.mon x0  see : http://www.ing.unitn.it/~grass/docs/tutorial/english/terminale_en.htm

Comment: Without an X Server you cannot use the classical GRASS monitors on Windows. But GRASS 6.4+ offers you a new graphical user interface with the same possibility to output into PNG files.

Comment: Yes, I could save the map into a PNG file using the "save" option in the wxPython based graphical user interface. Is there a way for me to save it into a PNG using a script because I will use another program to call it using a script. Unfortunately, d.mon is not working in order to make me use the d.out.file.

Comment: d.mon x0 does not work too. It produced errors: `ERROR: no such monitor 'x0'`

Comment: Did you read my answer from Feb 27 at 9:21?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `d.*` commands from the command-line window (which can be started alongside the GUI), or reconnect to your mapset with `grass -text` to get the command-line interface. You may want to also look at [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) for more sophisticated display, it has a GRASS plugin which allows it to access GRASS layers. It includes a print composer that can generate sophisticated maps, including image output in various formats.

Comment: I used the GRASS 6.4.0 with MSYS in order to type in the command-line window. I tried running `d.out.file` but the error was: `You must select a display monitor`. I tried `d.mon -l` to list the monitors but I have no monitors. I tried `d.mon start=1` but is displayed the error: `there was no such monitor 1`. I do not know how to start or create a monitor.

Comment: Did you read my answer from Feb 27 at 9:21?

Comment: @markusN: Yes I had read it. I was able to save the display using the graphical user interface to output into PNG files. But I cannot find a way to save a raster and vector (as one overlayed png file) without using the graphical user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you use the new graphical user interface (wxPython based). For this wxPython based interface, use the "Save display to graphics file" or "Print display" functionality from the icons bar on top of the map. See also the [manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/wxGUI.html).
See therein

- Save display to graphic file

  - Save the visible image in map display to different raster graphic formats.
- Print map

  - Prints map on system native printer or PostScript device; saves visible map display (including PostScript text and labels) to PDF or EPS file.

Comment: I was able to save it into a PNG file using the wxPython based graphical user interface. It would be better if I could save it into a PNG using a script because I will use another program to call it using a script. Unfortunately, d.mon is not working in order to make me use the d.out.file.

Comment: d.mon is a completely different technology than the wxpython interface. I'll investigate for a scripted approach for the wxpython interface.

Comment: Updated: currently there is no scriptable approach in wxGUI but it is scheduled in future GRASS 7 development.